# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers' with unique index 'IX_AspNetUsers_RegistrarId'

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have extended IdentityUser in ASP.NET-Core 3.1 application using EF-Core 3.1 on Visual Studio 2019 and I have the following fields defined

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
 {
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string OtherNames { get; set; }
    ...
    public string RegistrarId { get; set; }
    ...
     [ForeignKey("RegistrarId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Registrar { get; set; }
    ....
 }
```

This is the fluentApi for all the entities where some further relationships are required

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            // Each User can have many UserClaims
            b.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each User can have many UserLogins
            b.HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each User can have many UserTokens
            b.HasMany(e => e.Tokens)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each User can have many entries in the UserRole join table
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            b.HasIndex(e => e.Email)
                .IsUnique();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(b =>
        {
            // Each Role can have many entries in the UserRole join table
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each Role can have many associated RoleClaims
            b.HasMany(e => e.RoleClaims)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(rc => rc.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            b.HasMany(e => e.RoleRoutes)
            .WithOne(e => e.Role)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.RoleId)
            .IsRequired();       
        });          

        modelBuilder.Entity<RatedGroupCriterion>()
            .HasKey(rc => new {
                rc.RatedGroupId,
                rc.CriterionId
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RatedGroupCriterion>()
            .HasOne(reg => reg.RatedGroup)
            .WithMany(rgc => rgc.RelatedCriteria)
            .HasForeignKey(reg => reg.RatedGroupId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RatedGroupCriterion>()
            .HasOne(rc => rc.Criterion)
            .WithMany(rgc => rgc.RelatedEntities)
            .HasForeignKey(reg => reg.CriterionId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<InstructorCriterionRating>()
            .HasKey(irc => new { irc.InstructorRatingId, irc.CriterionId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<LessonCriterionRating>().HasKey(lrc => new { lrc.LessonRatingId, lrc.CriterionId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleErrand>().HasKey(rap => new { rap.RoleId, rap.ErrandId });

        modelBuilder.Seed();
    }
```

but I realized that after inserting the first record into the database table, I am having problem inserting further records into the same table and the error I get is as follows

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers' with unique index 'IX_AspNetUsers_RegistrarId'. The duplicate key value is (d75c86d4-32d8-4b34-8269-b31e3fd35d58). The statement has been terminated.

On checking the design view of my users table I saw the following

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AspNetUsers_RegistrarId]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([RegistrarId] ASC) 
WHERE ([RegistrarId] IS NOT NULL);
```

Therefore giving a unique constraint on the `RegistrarId` column but I cannot find where I added that condition/constraint or where/how to remove it properly. And because of this, I cannot continue adding more records to the database table.

Please help me if you can guide me on how to rectify this issue

Thank you

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: @XAMT, The problem is obviously from the table structure which is why the code is not able to insert further records into the table. It is not a question of the code that does the insertion because it succeeds in inserting the first record without issues.
Meanwhile, I already added the code for the entity that could have led to generating the table since I am  using a code-first approach

Comment: I asked for the ef code because I have same problem last week and find out its for business that calls DbSet.Entity.Add() twice. Also, there is nothing wrong with [ForeignKey] on the foreign key property in the dependent entity.

Comment: Do you have fluent configuration code affecting `ApplicationUser`? e.g. `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()....`? Because with the just shown entity class/data annotations the index must *not* be unique.

Comment: @IvanStoev, Yes I have but none of them is related to the affected entity. However, I have edited my question and included them.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. But at the same time I can't reproduce. How about adding explicitly `b.HasOne(e => e.Registrar).WithMany()` inside `ApplicationUser` configuration? The only reason of creating implicit unique constaint I know is if the relationship is considered one-to-one. Of course I'm assuming you are using EF Core migrations. The name of the index doesn't match the EF Core convention, are we sure it is created by EF Core migration?